# Collapsing all menus and hiding them at the same time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, menu

For some reason, I can't get jQuery menus to collapse and hide at the same time.  Individual calls to collapse or hide the menu work, just not at the same time.

For collapsing the menu, I'm using `$(menu).menu("collapseAll", null, true)` as stated via [the jQuery documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/menu/#method-collapseAll).

For hiding the menu, I'm calling `$(menu).hide()`, nothing fancy.  Here's [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/hide/).

And here's [a JSFiddle of what I'm trying to do](http://jsfiddle.net/u2v2x049/5/).  Pick a menu option, then click the "Show menu" button.  The menu is shown and collapses after about a half second in this example.  Ultimately, this menu will be used in many places of my code, so it's important that the menu isn't expanded to the last menu page when it's displayed to the user after its first appearance.

Comment: Do you mean why does the menu come back to view after you clicked on an item?

Comment: If you have a jsFiddle of what you want, why dont you use it?

Comment: @Huangism: No, I used a setTimeout to make the menu reappear to demonstrate that it never collapsed.  I edited my question to make this clearer.

Comment: @thinkwinwin: The jsFiddle doesn't do what I'm looking for; it demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Hmm... but if you use the body to show the menu again it works fine, http://jsfiddle.net/u2v2x049/4/

Comment: @Huangism: I can't seem to make the menu reappear in your example.  I have edited [my jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u2v2x049/5/) to contain a button that makes the menu reappear.

Comment: @Synthead you have to click on the text, because that's the only `body` left. It seems that timeout delay made the menus collapse in my fiddle, in yours it just does not work when it is first displayed

Comment: @Huangism: The `setTimeout` was as one method to make the menu reappear, since you've added a second way to make it reappear (clicking `<body>`), I've [removed the unnecessary `setTimeout`](http://jsfiddle.net/u2v2x049/6/) and the issue described in the question's jsFiddle is still reproducible.

Comment: @Synthead it seems like no matter what the menu remains open. I tried a bunch of different methods and all the same result

Comment: Collapse-all does not do what you are expecting -- it only collapses any **sub-menus** -- not the full menu structure. See my answer for a proposed solution.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this menu has a built in timeout when you click on an item, you can see this when you click on the items, the menu does not collapse right away. It hides right away because you have the `.hide()` and that executes right away.

The only way I can do what you want was

http://jsfiddle.net/u2v2x049/7/

```
$(function () {
    var menu = $("#menu");

    menu.menu({
        select: function (event, ui) {
            $(this).menu("collapseAll", null, true);
            setTimeout(function () {
                menu.hide();
            }, 500);
        }
    });

    $("button").click(function (event) {
        menu.show();
    });
});
```

So it collapses all of them then I hide the menu after 500 ms. You can make it 400 if you want. My guess is the menu probably checks for its visibility, and if it is not visible then it doesn't collapse properly. I don't really use this UI, this is all I can offer you.

Actually 300 ms seems to be perfect timing, http://jsfiddle.net/u2v2x049/8/

Comment: Hm, looks like this is a race condition from jQuery's own `setTimeout` calls to collapse the menu.  If I [reduce your `setTimeout` value to 300 to match what is apparently jQuery's `setTimeout` value](http://jsfiddle.net/u2v2x049/9/), the menu collapses and hides sans the little "animation" that happens with the 500 value.  Perhaps I can hook an event somewhere to avoid this `setTimeout` hack for the race condition?

Comment: @Synthead I can't offer any insight on the menu itself, I have never used it or jquery UI

Comment: I still see the stale menu pages appear every once in a while with the 300 ms `setTimeout`.  In reading jQuery UI's JS, the timeout value really is 300 ms, so this simply two timeouts in a race condition.  It'd be much better to hook jQuery UI's menu collapse to hide the menu, but I don't want to edit any of their JS or mangle the internals.

Comment: @Synthead maybe you can extend it so it calls an afterCollapse function or something like that. In that function you can define whatever you want yourself. I think this would be your best approach. This way you are not interfering with their original code, and your new method does nothing anyway if not defined by user

Answer (score 0):

The *collapse-all* method does not do what you are expecting:

> Indicates whether all **sub-menus** should be closed or only sub-menus below and including the menu that is or contains the target of the triggering event.

So, it's just for opening/closing the sub-menus - not the entire menu structure. Instead, you can enclose each menu structure in a DIV and:

(1) put `overflow:hidden;` on the containing div, and

(2) use jQuery to animate the div's height

Try this instead:

```
$('container_DIV').animate({
    height: '0px'
},800);
```

Here is a jsFiddle with a full demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/73jgv60a/

---

*In the fiddle, note that the menu vanishes off the screen when animation is completed. This is because both menu structures are floated left, and when the height of the first one becomes zero, the other one just moves into its place. To prevent this, if desired, wrap the outer container in another DIV that retains space on the page.*

---

The menu pages actually do open, but you cannot see them because the DIV is tight to the main menu, and has `overflow:hidden;`.

At first, I planned to chain `.css('overflow','hidden or visible')` to each toggle function, but it turns out that `overflow:hidden` does not seem to be required.

<kbd>[**Revised jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/73jgv60a/1/)</kbd>

Comment: This example doesn't hide the menu when its clicked and none of the menu pages open.  I know that `collapseAll` only closes the menu pages; this is why I'm also calling `.hide()`.

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice that. See addition to answer, and [revised jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/73jgv60a/1/).

Comment: I [added a button to your example](http://jsfiddle.net/73jgv60a/2/) to `.show()` `.menuDIV` and the menus still display the previously-selected pages.

Comment: Sorry, I don't seem to understand what is required. In the fiddle, I must not be looking at the correct area because I don't see [ previously selected pages ] -- what do you mean by that?  And, how do you want the fiddle to work differently? What are the menus supposed to do? How will you use them? And why did you choose the `menu()` widget over the `Selectmenu()` widget?

Comment: By the way, if any of these answers have been helpful, upvotes are always appreciated.